# I want to ask about deleteCharAt method

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I searched `deleteCharAt` method on API Documents. The return type of this method was `StringBuilder`. So I thought reference variables is needed to put reference value on.

For example, I think `sbuf=sbuf.deleteCharAt(0);` is better expression than `sbuf.deleteCharAt(0);`.

However, on many books and codes, the latter is used.

What's the false part in my thought?

Comment: `StringBuilder` often returns the same instance of `StringBuilder` so you can do method chaining `sbuf.append("Hello").deletCharAt(0)` == `ello`. This approach is often used by objects which implement the builder pattern, as it helps you reduce repeated code

Comment: I can understand your codes. But In this code 'sbuf.deleteCharAt(0);', where is the instance returned? to Java Compiler? or Main method?

Comment: Consider the expression being evaluated step by step; `sbuf` evaluates as a reference to a StringBuffer instance, a method is called on that instance and so `sbuf.deleteCharAt(0)` evaluates as a reference to a StringBuffer instance, and so on. The instance is returned from deleteCharAt method out to the calling expression.

Comment: No where.  You can call a method which has a return value and ignore it.  Not always wise, but it can be done.  `StringBuilder` is mutable, so changes made to it (like `deleteCharAt`) effect the internal contents, but for convience, it will return `this` (an instance of the `StringBuilder`) so you can chain method calls together

Answer (score 2):

The StringBuilder object is mutable; once you call the operation `.deleteCharAt()`, the reference `sbuf` is still to the same object, and the internal state of that object has changed. So you can call the method in the form `sbuf.deleteCharAt(0);`.

Strings, for example, are not mutable, though. When you call the `.substring()` method, say, it returns a reference to an entirely new instance of the string class. So if you wrote `str.substring(5);`, the return value would be thrown away and `str` would still have it's old value. Instead, you need to write something like `newStr = str.substring(5);` in the case of immutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

In java, `String` objects are `immutable`. Once string object is created its data or state can't be modified but a new string object is created.

Consider the example given below:

```
class Demo{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
   String s="Demo";  
   s.concat("String");//concat() method appends the string at the end  
   System.out.println(s);
 }  
}
```

**Output:**

> Demo

Here, the new modified string literal is created and discarded.

If we assign it to the reference variable, it will refer to modified object.For example:

```
class Demo{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
   String s="Demo";  
   s=s.concat("String");  
   System.out.println(s);  
 }  
}
```

**Output:**

> DemoString

Java `StringBuilder` class is used to create mutable string.

```
class Demo{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
     StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("Demo");  
     sb.append("String");//now original string is changed  
     System.out.println(sb);  
  }  
}
```

**Output:**

> DemoString